# rename a zipped file in python

Tags: python, zip, file-rename

I have a zipped file. 
Inside of it I have a`.tvx` file - which I want to rename to `.xml` .
 So I tried the following: (of course, I imported all the relevant modules).

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if not os.path.isdir(filename):
             os.rename(filename,filename.replace("tvx","xml"))
```

and the error I got was:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I thought that maybe the error was because the filename is not in absolute path,

so I tried also this:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(complete_name) as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
    if not os.path.isdir(filename):
        filename=os.path.abspath(filename) #making filename absolute path
        os.rename(filename,filename.replace("tvx","xml"))
```

but still, the same error.

Comment: You can't modify zip content using Python. But you can regenerate it.

Comment: You could parse the zip file for its directory, and change the name there. You do realise surely that the contents of the zip file are not part of the filesystem?

Comment: yes. of course. that was my confusion. I just extracted the file - and renamed the files in the extracted folder. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't rename file within the zip file, So you should extract, rename and rezip the file.

Comment: You can modify the file name in the zip directory